# Erro em ViewBag: não contém uma definição para nome do campo

Tags: c#

Tenho essa ViewBag

```
ViewBag.LogAlteracao = _logAlteracaoRepository.Table.Where(log => log.OrderId == id).ToList();
```

Esse é o domínio

```
public class LogAlteracao : EntityBase
    {
        public DateTime? Data { get; set; }
        public string Acao { get; set; }
        public string Localizador { get; set; }
        public string Observacao { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
    }
```

Quando tento popular seja uma table ou uma lista na View, dessa forma, por exemplo

```
<div class="margin-40-b">
           <ul>              
               <li>
                   <label>Ação:</label>
                   @ViewBag.LogAlteracao.Acao
               </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
```

Pego esse erro

> Message='System.Collections.Generic.List "Core.Domain.Logs.LogAlteracao"' não contém uma definição para 'Acao'

O que pode estar acontecendo? Já removi o ToList() e mesmo assim nada.

***OBS: Coloquei aspas duplas, pois o sinal < ou > estava ocultando o resto da mensagem quando quotadas***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `ViewBag.LogAlteracao` que você está passando é uma lista.

E a `Acao` é uma propriedade de um `LogAlteracao`.

Coloque dentro de um loop, acesse o `ViewBag.LogAlteracao[i].Acao` e seja feliz :)